# active directory mvc without membership

Tags: model-view-controller, active-directory, membership-provider

I need to implement a mixed mode authentication both form and windows authentication in my Application using MVC 5

That means I need to implement Active directory Authentication without using ASP.NET membership provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want to use active directory user as ASP.NET Identity user..
Prepare a method for UserLogin info(for adding to ASPNET Idenity)

```
    private UserLoginInfo GetWindowsLoginInfo(string userId, string password)
    {
        string result = IsValidADUser(userId, password);
        return result != "" ? new UserLoginInfo("Windows", result) : null;
    }
```

and create a method for validating against active directory

```
private string IsValidADUser(string userName, string password)
    {

        String adServerName = "LDAP://<<your LDAP String>>";
        var sid = "";

    try
    {
        var directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(adServerName))
        {
            directoryEntry.Path = adServerName;
            directoryEntry.Username = userName;
                            directoryEntry.Password = password;
            directoryEntry.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid AD");
        }
        if (directoryEntry.NativeObject != null)
        {
            // Verify the user is locked or not
            DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry);
                            searcher.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + userName + ")";
            searcher.CacheResults = false;
            SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();

            if (result == null || result.Properties["lockoutTime"][0].ToString() != "0")
            {
                throw new Exception("User Account is locked");
            }
            else
            {
                var sidInBytes = (byte[])result.Properties["objectSid"][0];
                sid = new SecurityIdentifier(sidInBytes, 0).ToString();
                //isValidUser = true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("AD:" + ex.Message);
    }
    return sid;
}
```

Comment: Glad If I can be any help